# Lower critical Reynolds number

Tags: fluid-dynamics, definition, flow

The definition given in my text is : “is the value at which the flow remains laminar however agitated the tank water is “
I found that unclear.

Also , What other factors affect the critical value of Reynolds number than the viscosity and the speed of the fluid  if there’s any.

Comment: Which text is that?

Comment: It’s merely a book with notes of the lecturer

Comment: Have you looked at the relevant [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_number)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see laminar flow becomes turbulent by growth of disturbances introduced into it either by uncontrollable vibrations from the walls (which are ever present) or deliberately by using a trip wire. Beyond a Reynolds number smallest disturbances get amplified (in time and/or space) and laminar flow becomes turbulent. This state of the flow is analogous to a pencil standing on its pointed end. However there is also a Reynolds number (not true of all flows) below which disturbances get damped out and do not grow. This is perhaps what is being referred to in your notes.